# Setting current activity to an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to use one of the classes in [this example](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html) 
the example is showing a list and when the button is clicked another activity is opened 
the code for function I want to use

```
public class ChartDemo extends Activity {
    private AverageCubicTemperatureChart TCh = new AverageCubicTemperatureChart();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = TCh.execute(this);
    }
}
```

The code for the class **AverageCubicTemperatureChart**

```
/**
  * Average temperature demo chart.
 */
public class AverageCubicTemperatureChart implements IDemoChart  {
 /**
 * Returns the chart name.
 * 
* @return the chart name
*/
    public String getName() {
        return "Average temperature";
    }

    /**
    * Returns the chart description.
    * 
    * @return the chart description
    */
    public String getDesc() {
        return "The average temperature in 4 Greek islands (cubic line chart)";
    }

     /**
     * Executes the chart demo.
     * 
     * @param context the context
     * @return the built intent
     */
    public Intent execute(Context context) {
        String[] titles = new String[] { "Crete", "Corfu", "Thassos", "Skiathos" };
        List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
           x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 });
        }
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 23.6, 20.3, 17.2,
                                 13.9 });
        values.add(new double[] { 10, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 26, 26, 23, 18, 14, 11 });
        values.add(new double[] { 5, 5.3, 8, 12, 17, 22, 24.2, 24, 19, 15, 9, 6 });
        values.add(new double[] { 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 23, 26, 25, 22, 18, 13, 10 });
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW };
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND,
                                                PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.SQUARE };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = AbstractDemoChart.buildRenderer(colors, styles);
        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
        }
        AbstractDemoChart.setChartSettings(renderer, "Average temperature", "Month", "Temperature", 0, 100, 0, 100,
        Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.setXLabels(12);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 200, 0, 100 });
        renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 200, 0, 100 });
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getCubicLineChartIntent(context, AbstractDemoChart.buildDataset(titles, x, values),
        renderer, 0.33f, "Average temperature");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

The function named execute is returning an intent, how can I set my current view to that intent instead of starting a new activity

Comment: What you mean by "set my current view to that intent". You want to use  this view (temperature chart I guess) in your own activity?

Answer (score 0):

In the execute function I revived the context and the parent layout

at the end of the function and before returning intent I added this line

```
View mChartView2;
mChartView2=ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(context, AbstractDemoChart.buildDataset(titles, x, values), renderer, 0.33f); 
parent.addView(mChartView2);
```